# Linked list node assignment unexpectedly updates multiple variables

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am new to linked lists and just started to know the functions behind it. I have a question about assigning nodes. I believe this similar question has been repeated (if so, let me know), but I was watching videos about Linked List and I don't see them explaining of what I am about to ask here.

The question is, when I have a main node `head` and I assign a temporary `node.next` inside a method in a class `LinkedList`, why does `head` also get assigned as well?

I know you might not follow what I'm asking, but I'll present code and pics to help you understand.

Example code:

```
public void InsertNodeAtTail(int val)
{
    LinkedListNode node = new LinkedListNode(val);

    if (head == null)
        head = node;
    else
    {
        LinkedListNode current = head;
        while (current.next != null)
        {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = node; //???
    }
}
```

Basically, this is all done inside a class `LinkedList` and I am inserting a value at the list's tail.

Where I placed the comment `//???` is the line I'm curious about.

I ran a console program in VS2019 and placed breakpoints to understand what's going on. When a breakpoint hits after that line with comment which is `}`, `current.next` and `head.next` get assigned simultaneously. And I expect `current.next` to ONLY be assigned, not `head`.

Pics:

Before: https://prnt.sc/rwahho

So, both `head.next` and `current.next` are `null`.

After: https://prnt.sc/rwaiub

Both are assigned! Again I was expecting `current.next` to ONLY be assigned.

So, why did they both get assigned? Are there any explanation for this to happen? If there is any website or article you know to help me understand this, please let me know.

PS: I've added `head.next = current` after that line with comment and I ended up getting an endless list.

Comment: If `current` and `head` refer to the same node then modifications via one are reflected in the other. They both refer to the same object

Comment: Well, there is this line first: `LinkedListNode current = head;`, which starts `current` out at the `head` node. So both `current` and `head` are pointing to the same node, so any change to one will obviously be reflected in the other. Presumably the `while` loop didn't run (which happens if `head.next == null`), which is why you see both get modified. In other words, the `head` node was the only node, so it's also the `tail` node, and is the node that `current` was referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InsertNodeAtTail` will take a value, create a node from it, traverse the list until it gets to the end, and then insert the node.

A linked list is comprised of nodes that have a value and a next property (which points to the next node in the list). The beginning of the list is defined by a node called the `head`. Traversing the list involves starting at the head and then repeatedly moving to the `.Next` node (in a loop), until a `null` value is found (the last node in the list will have a `null` value for `.Next`).

The first thing the code does is check to see if `head` is `null`. If it is, then it means we have an empty list, so there is no "head" (or "tail"), and therefore the value being inserted becomes the `head`.

If the `head` is *not* `null`, then we create a node called `current` which we will use to traverse the list. We start by assigning it to the `head` node, and we check to see if its `.Next` property is `null`.

---

**Answer**

At this moment in time, both `head` and `current` are referring to the same node. If `.Next` is `null`, then we assign our new node to the `.Next` property. Since both `current` and `head` are referring to the same node, *both* their `.Next` values are changed.

---

The next time we call `InsertNodeAtTail`, `current` will be assigned to `head.Next` (since it's not `null` because we just inserted a node here previously). Then the new value will be inserted by assigning it to *that* node's `.Next` property, and the `head` will remain unchanged (because `current` is no longer referring to `head`.

---

**VISUAL REPRESENTATION**

So to start with we have a NULL head, so the new node is assigned to head, with a `null` value for its `.Next`:

```
    head          
      ║
      ▼
╔═══════════╗ .Next
║ 1st value ║═══════► NULL
╚═══════════╝
```

The next time we run, we create a `current` node and point it to HEAD, and examine its `.Next` property. Since `.Next` is `null`, we insert the new value there. At this moment, both `head` and `current` are referring to the same node, so any change to one appears in the other as well:

```
    head          
      ║
      ▼
╔═══════════╗ .Next   ╔═══════════╗ .Next
║ 1st value ║═══════► ║ 2nd value ║═══════► NULL
╚═══════════╝         ╚═══════════╝
      ▲
      ║
   current
```

Then next time we run, `current` will move the the last node in the list (`head.Next` is not null, so `current` gets assigned to *that* node), and we will insert the node there. This time, `head` will remain unchanged, since `current` is no longer referring to it:

```
    head          
      ║
      ▼
╔═══════════╗ .Next   ╔═══════════╗ .Next   ╔═══════════╗ .Next    
║ 1st value ║═══════► ║ 2nd value ║═══════► ║ 3rd value ║═══════► NULL
╚═══════════╝         ╚═══════════╝         ╚═══════════╝
                            ▲
                            ║
                         current
```

---

If this still seems confusing, you might want to read about [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

A simple way to think about it is: `head` and `current` both "refer to a location in memory". This means that when we make a change to a property of `current` (like setting `current.Next` to some value), **we are actually making a change to the object at the address that it's referring to**.

So if we do `current.Next = someNode`, then `head.Next` will also equal `someNode`.

But when we make a change to `current` itself (and not the thing it refers to), by assigning it to a whole new node, **then we are changing the address in memory to which it refers.**

So if we do an assignment like `current = head.Next`, then any change to `head.Value` will not affect `current.Value` because they're referring to different nodes.

---

**Another way to think about it**

Pretend we're looking at houses, and we have two realtors (`head` and `current`). We've asked one of them to look at a property (`head = newNode;`), and we've asked the other one to look at the same property address (`current = head`), and then asked them each to describe it to us. In this case, we'll get the same answer from each of them (it has 2 beds, 1 bath, is 800 square feet, etc).

And if someone comes and adds a swimming pool to the property (`current.Next = anotherNode`), the next time we ask either of them about it, they will both tell us that there was a new pool added.

Next imagine that we asked one of them to look at a different address (`current = current.Next`). This time, when we ask each realtor to describe the current property they're looking at, we'll get two completely different descriptions, because they're looking at two different addresses.

Comment: This is pretty straight forward since I can see that this all makes sense because of the assignment is referring to the location of the memory. I'll read more about reference type since I definitely need to have a solid understanding of what it all is. But, overall, thanks allot for explaining me.

Comment: Yep, just found out, reference is what I needed to know. Came up with this example code: https://prnt.sc/rwe6cu. Now this all makes sense, reference is what I had to learn and I was kind of surprised that I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when variables are aliased. `LinkedListNode current = head;` doesn't create a deep copy of `head`'s memory, it merely gives you an additional variable to use to access it. This is necessary because reassignments need to happen to `current` in order for it to walk the linked list--we'd lose track of the class' `head` node if we used it directly in an assignment like `head = head.next`.

So, as an object in memory, we can assume `head` looks like this (for a single-element linked list):

```
.------.
| val  |
| next -> null
`------`
   ^
   |
[variable `head`]
```

Then, we execute `LinkedListNode current = head;` (notice that there is no `new` keyword--no new memory has been allocated). The program's state is now:

```
.------.
| val  |
| next --> null
`------`
   ^ ^
   | |
   | +----[variable `current`]
   |
[variable `head`]
```

You can see that two variables point to the same memory location. The line `while (current.next != null)` is false because `next` is null, so we never enter the loop body for this degenerate linked list.

Finally, we execute `current.next = node;`:

```
      [variable: `node`]
             |
             v
.------.  .------.
| val  |  | val  |
| next -->| next --> null
`------`  `------`
   ^ ^
   | |
   | +----[variable `current`]
   |
[variable `head`]
```

We've mutated the object that both `current` and `head` are references to. This is what your debugger is showing you and it's perfectly normal. When the block ends, `head` still points to the logical head of the list and we added our new tail. `current` seems pointless here, but if we'd had a longer list, the `while` loop would have been executed and `current` would have stopped aliasing `head`, enabling us to traverse to the end of the list without losing track of `head`.

This would look something like, for example, adding a new node to a 3-element list after executing `current.next = node;`:

```
                        [variable: `node`]
                                 |
                                 v
.------.  .------.  .------.  .------.
| val  |  | val  |  | val  |  | val  |
| next -->| next -->| next -->| next --> null
`------`  `------`  `------`  `------`
   ^                   ^
   |                   |
   |                   +----[variable `current`]
   |
[variable `head`]
```

Comment: Nice explanation, I've been a bit confused by this also